# Select Additional Field from another Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query,

This basically selects all rows in table 1when the type is present in table2.
However there is a column in table2 named age which I also want to print.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE exists (select * from table2 where type = table1.type ) 
AND color = 'blue';
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try `INNER JOIN` ?

```
SELECT table1.*,table2.age from
table1
inner join 
table2 on table1.type=table2.type
and table1.coloe='blue'
```

You have written kind of recursive query, I'm not sure what are you trying with it. But, it will definitely hit the performance of your query.